# How to detect dynamically if the app is under local/online environment

Tags: jsp, servlets

greetings all
i want to detect dynamically if the application is under local environment (development) or online server environment, through the httpservletRequest maybe , i don't know, any ideas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I always do it in the configuration file, and manage the development and production configuration files as two separate entities (i.e. in separate places within version control)

Answer (score 0):

You could try using `getRequestURL()` on your `HttpServletRequest` object to retrieve the URL that is being requested. Then search that string for "localhost" or your development IP address.